# outputing greatests() timestamps returns nulls sql, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three dates data_a,date_b & date_main. All of them `TIMESTAMP` that outputs values likes this 2018-06-20 11:11:20.

Sometimes date_a or date_b are NULL, date_main is always present (NOT NULL).

Why when trying to compare them using GREATEST(), it outputs blanks (NULL) values ""?

```
 GREATEST(MAX(l.date_a),MAX(r.date_b),p.date_main) AS date,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values for every column that is nullable:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(MAX(l.date_a), '1900-01-01'),
         COALESCE(MAX(r.date_b), '1900-01-01'),
         p.date_main
)AS date
```

As you want greatest value I would exchange `NULL` with some date from the past(arbitrary value).

Comment: ok, I didnt expected that...Why `coalesce()` and why `1900-01-01`? thank you

Answer (score 2):

If `p.date_main` is never `NULL`, I would use:

```
GREATEST(COALESCE(MAX(l.date_a), p.date_main),
         COALESCE(MAX(r.date_b), p.date_main),
         p.date_main
        ) AS date,
```

`GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` (unlike `MIN()` and `MAX()`) return `NULL` if *any* of the arguments are `NULL`.  So, if all the values in a group are `NULL`, then `MIN()` and `MAX()` return `NULL`.  The `COALESCE()` replaces the value with `p.date_main` for the comparison for the greatest value.